setting up gnome remote desktop via cli. grdctl issues with ubuntu 24.04
root@ubuntu-24:~# grdctl --help
Usage: grdctl [OPTIONS...] COMMAND [SUBCOMMAND]...
Commands:
  rdp                                        - RDP subcommands:
    set-port                                 - Set port the server binds to
    enable                                   - Enable the RDP backend
    disable                                  - Disable the RDP backend
    set-tls-cert <path-to-cert>              - Set path to TLS certificate
    set-tls-key <path-to-key>                - Set path to TLS key
    set-credentials <username> <password>    - Set username and password
                                               credentials
    clear-credentials                        - Clear username and password
                                               credentials
    enable-view-only                         - Disable remote control of input
                                               devices
    disable-view-only                        - Enable remote control of input
                                               devices
    enable-port-negotiation                  - If unavailable, listen to
                                               a different port
    disable-port-negotiation                 - If unavailable, don't listen
                                               to a different port

  status [--show-credentials]                - Show current status

Options:
  --headless                                 - Use headless credentials storage
  --system                                   - Configure system daemon
  --help                                     - Print this help text
root@ubuntu-24:~# grdctl rdp enable 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

when running gdb bt
(gdb) bt
#0  create_settings (runtime_mode=GRD_RUNTIME_MODE_SCREEN_SHARE) at ../src/grd-ctl.c:690
#1  main (argc=3, argv=0x7ffc72724928) at ../src/grd-ctl.c:1031

Has anyone been able to configure gnome remote desktop via the command line using grdctl?
I have tried most of the commands and cannot get anything besides --help to work. I also tried setting up a local user with the same issues
I can run the gnome remote desktop service with
machinectl shell --uid (username) and systemctl start --user gnome-remote-desktop.service. I still see the issue

after reading https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-remote-desktop/+bug/2063333
I ran
sudo systemd-sysusers
sudo systemd-tmpfiles --create /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/gnome-remote-desktop-tmpfiles.conf
sudo systemd-sysusers /usr/lib/sysusers.d/gnome-remote-desktop-sysusers.conf
sudo systemd-tmpfiles --create /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/gnome-remote-desktop-tmpfiles.conf
mkdir /etc/gnome-remote-desktop/

to resolve the issue
